# "At-the-money Implied as a Robust Approximation of the Volatility Swap Rate."

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, swaps, vix

Does anyone know where to get this paper?

Carr, Peter and R. Lee, January 2004, "At-the-money Implied as a Robust Approximation of the Volatility Swap Rate."

On google scholar the paper appears to be a working paper (from 2004) from Bloomberg. So maybe should be asking how to access academic papers from Bloomberg.

Comment: With a paper this old it is likely that parts have been published by the authors in other papers or for other reasons it won't be published on its own. If you are seriously interested in seeing it the best bet is to write a polite email to one of the authors.

Comment: Indeed I did do that, and Dr. Carr kindly sent it to me immediately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is not suited for the SE Q&A format (it asked for a paper).